# Prove $(Imz)^2$ is not holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that the function $(Imz)^2$ is not homolomorphic in any subset of $\mathbb{C}$

I know I need to use Cauchy Riemann's equation where

$\frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{du}{dx}$ and $\frac{dv}{dx} = -\frac{du}{dy}$

But I don't know what $(Imz)^2$ is equal to

Answer (score 2):

If $z = x + iy$, then $(\operatorname{Im}{(z)})^2 = y^2$. Hence, $f(z) = u(x,y) + i\cdot v(x,y),$ where $u(z) = y^2$ and $v(z) = 0.$ We now get:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0,\,\, \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0,\,\, -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -2y$$